# ImportError na instalação do OpenCV

Tags: python, instalador, opencv

Hoje tentei reinstalar a biblioteca do opencv no meu computador, fiz isso pelo `script pip`, qual baixei o arquivo `.whl` pelo site:  `http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/`.

Após a biblioteca ter sido instalada com sucesso, assim que eu entrei no IDLE, apareceu:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: conseguir instalar, precisei baixar os arquivos .dll: msvcp71.dll e msvcr71.dll conforme vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmvRF7koJ5E